# Why can't my calculator program calculate operator / aka. divsision properly?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void run_calc();
void scandata(char *op, double  *operand);
void do_next_op(char op, double operand, double *sum);
int main()
{
run_calc();
return 0;
}
void run_calc(){
double sum, operand;
char op, answer;
printf("Press enter to use the calculator\n");

scanf("%c", &answer);
while(answer!='q'&& answer!='Q')
{
printf("Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program.");
scandata(&op, &operand);
do_next_op(op, operand, &sum);
printf("Result so far is: %1.2lf \n", sum);
}
}

void scandata(char *op, double *operand) {
scanf(" %c", op);

if(*op =='+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op =='/' || op =='^' ){
scanf ("%lf", operand);
}

}
void do_next_op(char op, double operand, double *sum)
{
switch(op)
{
case '+': *sum += operand; break;
case '-': *sum -= operand; break;
case '*': *sum *= operand; break;
case '/': *sum = (operand == 0) ? *sum  : *sum / operand; break;
case '^': *sum = pow(*sum,operand); break;
case '#': *sum = (*sum >= 0) ? sqrt(*sum) : *sum; break;
case '%': *sum *= *sum -1; break;
case '!': *sum =  (1 / *sum); break;
case '@': *sum = log(*sum); break;
case 'q': printf(" The final value of akku is %1.2lf \n", *sum);  exit(0); defult: break;
}
}
```

Here is the conversaton when i input /2 which should give me 5 but it give me 2

```
Press enter to use the calculator
Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program.+5
Result so far is: 5.00
Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program.+5
Result so far is: 10.00
Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program./2
Result so far is: 2.00
Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program.Result so far is: 2.00
Enter an operator (+,-,/,#,^,*) and optional operand.Enter 'h' for help. Enter 'q' to exit the program.
```

How can i make it calculate correctly? and if an user input /0, i want the program to just print Result so far of sum, if not then just *sum/operand.

I think i did it right but i cant see the issue here. can someone help me?

Comment: Please indent your code before posting it.  Lack of proper indentation invites bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
if(*op =='+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op =='/' || op =='^' ){
```

You dereferenced `op` to compare with `'+'`, but didn't dereference that to compare with other things.

Have it dereference for the other operators will improve the behavior.

```
if(*op =='+' || *op == '-' || *op == '*' || *op =='/' || *op =='^' ){
```